How can I clean behind the grid of holes on the inside compartment of a microwave oven?
There was an egg explosion in my LG Microwave (don't ask).  I managed to clean up the surfaces but am concerned about the food that may have made its way through the grid of holes in the interior walls of the cooking compartment.  My primary concern is to prevent mold or bacterial growth between the interior and exterior walls of the microwave.

First, don't be too concerned:

Egg is viscous, and most was stuck to the inside of the oven, rather than going through the small holes.
The continual heating of the oven will leave innocuous, dried egg, unlikely to breed microcritters.

As the egg dries more, and crumbles, you could vacuum the grid to remove the loose stuff.
While it is possible to remove the outside box of the microwave oven and clean inside the microwave, I'd not recommend doing so:

Specialized tools might be needed, such as security screwdrivers, hex or Torx bits.
Even after being unplugged for a while, capacitors inside can retain a dangerous amount of power at high voltage (1,000 - 2,000 V).
A mistake in reassembly can cause microwave leakage.

